# SXA Theme doesn't load with Snippet in Experience Editor

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA 9.1.1 I have created a theme and it works fine with my pages. But when I go to Data-> Snippets and open a snippet in Experience Editor, then my theme doesn't load. Maybe it loads the SXA default theme.

Is there any setting that I am missing? or Is it the behaviour of SXA that we need to add a snippet from a page, not directly from the Data -> Snippet folder?

Comment: This should be the default behavior of SXA. When you open the snippet alone in Exp Editor, it uses the default Wireframe so that components can be configured but snippets at the end of the day needs to be integrated to a page which will use the Page Design and thus the theme to render the components properly with the styles.